# Possible to replace tokenized values within a .properties file within Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, tokenize

Possible to replace tokenized values within a .properties file within Jenkins?

Iam running an automation project in Jenkins which uses Java, I have a central config.properties file, is there a feature within Jenkins which would enable me to replace tokenized values via the Jenkins portal?

Current Config .properties File:

```
<!--BROWSER TYPE: chrome | firefox -->
browser=#{browserType}#

<!--BASE BAG HOMEPAGE URL: www.google.com
url=#{homepageUrl}#

<!--Username: example21@mail.com !-->
username=#{username}#
```

I need to replace all values which are contained within: #{}# therefore if i set the variable: browser with the value chrome then jenkins would replace the value and the end product would be:

```
<!--BROWSER TYPE: chrome | firefox -->
browser=chrome
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, properties files are not updated on the fly , you can use a sed instead

```
sed -i "s|#{browserType}#|${browser_jenkins build_variable}|g" Config .properties
```

browser_jenkins build_variable : This would a build parameter which you select when building the job

Updated solution :

1. define a jenkins build parameter ( choice ) as : browser_value ( variable name)
2. update your Config.properties file as

   ```
   browser=browser_value
   ```
3. Use a execute shell and use below command

   ```
    sed -i "s|browser_value|${browser_value}|g" Config.properties
   ```

The above command should replace the browser_value string in config.properties with the option you select in jenkins job choice parameter

Comment: thanks would i replace the build_variable with a specific value?